# The name 'GUIUtilities' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I got this error message when trying to run the project. Even I already import UnityEngine namespace, the error message still occur.

```
Assets/Scripts/QRCodeReaderGUI.cs(14,22): error CS0103: The name 'GUIUtilities' does not exist in the current context
```

My code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class QRCodeReaderGUI : MonoBehaviour {

    public GUIStyle buttonTextStyle;
    public GUIStyle textStyle;
    float SizeFactor;

    private string qrCode;

    void Start()
    {
        SizeFactor = GUIUtilities.SizeFactor;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        SizeFactor = GUIUtilities.SizeFactor;
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        if (GUIUtilities.ButtonWithText(new Rect(
            Screen.width - 200 * SizeFactor,
            0,
            200 * SizeFactor,
            100 * SizeFactor), "Back", null, buttonTextStyle) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("backFromARScene", 1);
            Application.LoadLevel("MainMenu");
        }

        GUIUtilities.Text(new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, 300 * SizeFactor), "Last QR code read: \n" + qrCode, textStyle);
    }

    public void setCode(string qrCode)
    {
        this.qrCode = qrCode;
    }
}
```

Reference: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUIUtility.html

Answer (score 1):

Try putting:
using UnityEngine.GUIUtility;

If not working, try to see if that component works well in Unity 5.0. The new version changed a lot the way GUI Works.

Alternatively,you could use UI.Text and put:
using UnityEngine.UI;

Answer (score 0):

Same was for me, i was trying to use GUI.Box() method. GUI is in UnityEngine.IMGUIModule.dll. I copied that dll from the game to my project, opened project file, added in dependencies using Solution Explorer the file i copied, project file changed, but not autosaved changes for some reason. Then i presses ctrl+s, then tried to build again and saw 'Build Succes'. Yeah, odd.